# Modal doesn't show after redirect to page

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I've a problem with modal. It doesn't appear after success update.
I've a method with get request which return `redirect:/users` page.
And I try to pass a variable to this view by `modelAndView.addObject("activated", true);`
but inside this html page I've got always null value.
My code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUser(@PathVariable("id") BigInteger id, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    modelAndView.addObject("success", true);
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

What can be a problem?
I only think that is something with this redirect, because in this method I don't have to setViewName, but I had to do it to pass a variable to correct template.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please post the [minimal, complete or verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question

Comment: You can look above pls

Comment: I also tried to setViewName("users"); but still don't work